# Custom Profile Users are unable to view other users in org, there is no "View All Users" flag in Profile

Tags: user, user-management, custom-profile

In one of the Org, Custom Profile Users are unable to view other users in org, and there is no "View All Users" flag in Profile.

In other Orgs, Same profile users can see other users even when there is no "View All Users" flag in Profile. Can be config difference in Orgs.

"View All Users" flag is available just for an Admin Profile (Has Modify All and other Admin Privileges) in all Orgs.

Is there any setting/permission which would enable profile users to see all other Users ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if the Organization-Wide Defaults for User is set to 'Private' in the org that has this issue?

If it is, change it to 'Public Read Only' so that a user can see other users.

**Note:** *I am only writing my comments/suggestions as an Answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question*.

Comment: You are correct, it was set to private for "Default Internal Access” in OWD permissions.
Changing permission to 'Public Read Only' worked. Non Admin Users can see other Users now. 

Thanks!!